# Embedding layers trained on Amazon Reviews

Tags: word-embeddings, sentiment-analysis

I am working on research to perform sentiment analysis on Amazon reviews. My data is not labelled so I am now using Lexicon based sentiment analysis such as Vader. I am wondering if it is possible to use embedding layers to perform sentiment analysis in an unsupervised manner? Are there any pre-trained embedding layers on Amazon reviews that I can use? Thank you very much in advance.